# Cassandra: Is manual bucketing still needed when applying TWCS?

Tags: cassandra, partitioning

I am just about to start exploring Cassandra for (long term) saving time series (write only once) data, that potentially can grow quite large.

Assuming the probably most simple time series:

```
CREATE TABLE raw_data (
    sensor uuid,
    timestamp timestamp,
    value int,
    primary key(sensor, timestamp)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timestamp DESC)
```

To make sure, partitions don't grow too much, many posts on the internet recommend bucketing, e.g. introducing day or just an up counting bucket number like

```
primary key((sensor, day, bucket), timestamp)
```

. However, these strategies need to be managed manually what seems quite cumbersome especially for unknown number of buckets.

But, what if I say add:

```
  AND compaction = {
     'class': 'TimeWindowCompactionStrategy', 
     'compaction_window_size': 1, 
     'compaction_window_unit': 'DAYS'
  };
```

As said e.g. in https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/12/08/TWCS-part1.html:

> TWCS aims at simplifying DTCS by creating time windowed buckets of SSTables that are compacted with each other using the Size Tiered Compaction Strategy.

As far as I understand this means that Cassandra when using TWCS internally creates readonly buckets anyway. Thus, I am wondering if I still need to manually implement the bucketing key `day`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the bucket is to stop the partition growing too large. Without the bucket the growth of the partition is unbounded - that is, the more data you collect for a particular sensor, the larger the partition becomes, with no ultimate limit.

Changing the compaction strategy alone will not stop growth of the partition, so you would still need the bucket.

(You wrote "Cassandra when using TWCS internally creates readonly buckets". Don't confuse this with the 'bucket' column. The same word is being used for two completely different things.)

On the other hand, if you were to set a TTL on the data then this would effectively limit the size of the partition because data older than the TTL would (eventually) be deleted from disc. So, if the TTL were small enough, you would no longer need the bucket. In this particular scenario - timeseries data collected in-order and a TTL - then TWCS is the optimum compaction strategy.

Comment: Handling a bucket column really is not much trouble. The greatest inconvenience is if you want to query for the earliest, or latest, timestamp in all buckets - which you can't really do. For all other queries it is just a matter of executing one per bucket (which can run in parallel) and stitching together the results. In Python this is completely trivial using itertools.chain.from_iterable()

Comment: Hmm, what if I say defined dynamic buckets (depending on size) and just don't know, how much are insight? I guess I would have to store the number of buckets in another table, to be able to query them all?